# How to get printer font names in X window?

Tags: linux, printing, fonts

I can get the list of available printer fonts by calling Delphi's *TPrinter* methods which I believe in turn calls Windows GDI (such as *CreateFontA()* ?). I do this in WINE running in Debian. I do not know why, but luckily this list contains true type font names, which I need most but are not shown by command *xlsfonts*. I am not sure if this is relevant to the technology under the hood, but package *CUPS* is installed.

This successful experience makes me to think that WINE must in turn call some Linux API (X, xfs, ...?) and then provide my program the results I want.

Now I would like to get the same list directly from Linux in C or C++. Which way should I take in order to achieve this goal? What API documentations should I study?

Answer (score 0):

[WINE font](http://wine-wiki.org/index.php/Fonts) inspires me a lot, but I decide to stop researching the solution for my own question as the technology required to retrieve printer fonts in X window seems to be not trivial. I choose to use the font list given by Delphi's *TPrinter* running in WINE instead.

I close this question.